# allow english and arabic numbers input UITextField swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nscharacterset

I write code that only allow english number in `UITextField` and I want to check arabic numbers and allow thats.

this is my code :

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let textString = "0123456789_"
        let cs : NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: textString).invertedSet

        let filter = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(cs).joinWithSeparator("") as String

        return string == filter
    }
```

in my code I want allow english number and remove button now I want add arabic numbers in it.
I try with this : `let textString = "0123456789_۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"` but this not working!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through to see what is happening?  What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: @Paulw11 when input is one of ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹ return false and don't allow show it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it !!! hahahahahaha :D

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

//        let textString = "0123456789_۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"
        let cs : NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet

        if string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(cs) == nil {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does that rely on the `NSLocale`? If not, it may allow *any* script's digits.